# Wrong sys.path in jupyter notebook when launched in a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, sys.path

I created a virtual environment named `sampleenv`, however when I launched jupyter notebook inside sampleenv, I noticed that it is referencing/siting python packages from my another virtual environment named `openfaceenv`. Here's the output when calling `sys.path` and `sys.executable` inside jupyter notebook:

(Inside jupyter notebook in `sampleenv`)

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

> ['',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>    '',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib-18.18.99-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg',
>    '/Users/user',
>    '/Users/user/git-repos',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python27.zip',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>    '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
>    '/Users/user/.ipython']

```
print sys.executable
```

> /Users/user/.virtualenvs/openfaceenv/bin/python2.7

However when I ran ipython or python shell in command line in sampleenv and get the sys.path and sys.executable both of them correctly sites the right path, That is,

(Inside a python shell or ipython shell in `sampleenv`)

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

> ['', '/Users/user', '/Users/user/git-repos', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

```
print sys.executable
```

> '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/sampleenv/bin/python'

Why is this so? How can I fix this? Also, when I tried to switch to other virtual envs, same issue, it is pointing the path to that of the `openfaceenv` site-packages.I already look at the related problems, but their solution doesn't really solve the problem, I don't want to use `sys.path.append()`, also I tried running `hash -r`, but same result.

Comment: did you check whether you hardcoded a PYTONPATH in bashrc  or system environment setting?

Comment: no, I didn't change or modify PYTHONPATH variable

Comment: In your user root folder, execute `fgrep -lR "openfaceenv" ` to see any config file is put the entry there.

Comment: the command is taking too long, and there are no outputs, should I wait for it to finish?

Comment: `user` root, not the root.   It shouldn't take long, unless you have multiple GB data in your user folder.

Comment: yes you mean in my home directory?, I see that might be the reason, got 300 gb worth.

Comment: Use this `fgrep -lRI "openfaceenv"`   . first switch is a small "L" , the third switch is an capital  "i" . This will skip the binary check.  If this is too tedious, I will just create another user, then recreate the whole proiject.

Comment: Did you ever fix this @bninopaul??? I'm having the exact same problem.